# Searching for a specific file with testdisk

Tags: data-recovery, testdisk

Is there a way to recover just `.webm` files from a formatted partition using `testdisk` or `photorec`?

I have not enough space to recover all files and then find `.webm` files afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [list of file formats that PhotoRec can handle](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec), `.webm` is supported so I'd start with that tool first.

Going through the [step by step instructions](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step) you can specify that you're only interested in `.webm` or let it find everything. PhotoRec will recover all the files that match the types specified, after which you can then go through the netted results and delete whatever you do not want to keep.

[image: ss #1]

In your scenario you'd direct it to do the whole partition:

[image: ss #2]

Depending on what you specified for file formats you'll get a report similar to this:

[image: ss #3]

#### webm missing from file options menu?

In looking at version 6.14, which appears to be the latest, the file format `webm` appears to be missing however.

*excerpt from File Opt menu*

```
...
 [X] vmdk VMWare
 [X] vmg  Nokia Text Message
 [X] wallet Armory bitcoin wallet
>[X] wdp  JPEG XR
 [X] wim  Windows imaging (WIM) image
 [X] win  Opera preferences
 [X] wks  Lotus 1-2-3
 [X] wmf  Microsoft Windows Metafile
 [X] wnk  Wink
 [X] wpb  OpenCanvas
 [X] wpd  Corel Documents
...
```

So I would open a ticket up on the main project's website alerting them to this issue.

Comment: I have downloaded the most recent from repo. But I cannot find `.webm` extension. Even there's not `.mp4`.

Comment: What version from the repo are you using?

Comment: PhotoRec 6.14, Data Recovery Utility, July 2013

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - is there anything special w/ these webm files? The codes been there since 2011: http://git.cgsecurity.org/cgit/testdisk/commit/src?id=5b83e83701508bfdfa2298b9bf468acc548ced7b. If it isn't working I'd be inclined to open a ticket on the projects website. All indications would seem to imply that it should work.

Comment: .webm is not provided in the list given to select. There a `custom Own custom signature` probably for other files. But does not recover .webm files. .webm files are supported when all extensions are selected. But I have not enough space to collect all of them. Probablt there's an equivalent extension

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - confirming it's not in my list either. Warrants a ticket being opened on the project's website.

Comment: I am using Photorec version 6.14 and it is able to recover webm videos. I only enabled the following filetypes: asf, png, jpg, gif, mkv, mov, mpg, xcf.

Comment: I can confirm that the .mkv extension also finds the .webm files. Also, the [Photorec filetype list](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/File_Formats_Recovered_By_PhotoRec) says that both .mkv and .webm are Matroska.